# Problem About unitary operators

Tags: operator-theory

Suppose $H(t)$ is a operator defined as follows:
$$T(t+\epsilon,t)=1-\frac{i\epsilon}{\hbar}H(t)$$
Show that if $H(t)$ is hermitian, $T$ must be unitary. Suppose $\epsilon^2$ can be neglected.

I tried first finding $H(t)$:
$$H(t)=\frac{\hbar}{i\epsilon}(1-T(t+\epsilon,t))$$
Then applying the properties of Hermitian operators:
$$H^{\dagger}=H$$
But I did not get a satisfactory answer. Please give me some advices. Thanks.

Comment: What have you attempted towards solving this problem? What parts are giving you trouble or are difficult to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint*: $T$ is unitary if $T^\dagger T = I$ (identity), so find $T^\dagger$ and use that $H$ is Hermitian and that $\epsilon^2$ is negligible to prove that $T$ satisfies the identity above.